# Angular Checked Radio button, did not work

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I wrote following code to checked a radio button. User selected value is passed from an another page.
Based on that value I tried to select a radio button.

These are the ways I tried,

```
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input [value]="AND" [checked]="(as_op==AND) ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> AND
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input [value]="OR" [checked]="(as_op==OR) ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> OR
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input [value]="NOT" [checked]="(as_op==NOT) ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> NOT
    </label>
```

Then try, (wrap values using single quotes)

```
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input [value]="AND" [checked]="(as_op=='AND') ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> AND
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input [value]="OR" [checked]="(as_op=='OR') ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> OR
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input [value]="NOT" [checked]="(as_op=='NOT') ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> NOT
    </label>
```

But both ways did not work, Someone please explain the issue of the code. Thank you.

Comment: could you provide component code and expected result..

Answer (score 0):

remove the [] for value like below.

```
   <label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="AND" [checked]="(as_op=='AND') ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> AND
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="OR" [checked]="(as_op=='OR') ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> OR
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input value="NOT" [checked]="(as_op=='NOT') ? 'true' : 'false'" type="radio" [(ngModel)]="as_op" name="as_op"/> NOT
    </label>
```